# Can I run xcode 4.3.3 without lion?

Tags: xcode

My current version of xcode is 4.0, which doesn't support iOS 5. However, when I tried to download the latest version, 4.4, it said I needed to upgrade to lion.

I'm wondering if I can download a less recent version of xcode. My current os version is 10.6.8; would I be able to use xcode version 4.3.3?

Comment: If you aren't running Lion, it isn't possible that you're running Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If I remember correctly, Xcode 4.2 was the last version you could run without Lion.

Comment: I was forced to upgrade to Lion in order to use XCode 4.3.x

Answer (score 0):

At https://connect.apple.com/ you are able to download the entire dmg for Xcode, even for older versions, but you must be registered as an Apple developer.

Comment: I have the dev license, and I was able to download it. I'm just not sure if it'll run

Comment: no, you can't run it if you don't meet the minimum requirements. Anyway i was reffering to this part of your question "I'm wondering if I can download a less recent version of xcode."